# "Свидетельствовать происходящему" - слова на своих местах?

Tags: выбор-слов, архаизмы

> Папа Климент XIII (1758–1769) был рождён в Венеции, но на протяжении
>   всей своей римской жизни так или иначе свидетельствовал происходящему.

Может, какой-то устаревший оборот, с которым одна бедная я не знакома?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И всё-таки это устаревшее сочетание, как верно отметил Alex_ander, синонимичное "быть свидетелем чему?", это вариант современного "быть свидетелем чего?".

От "свидетель" - "свидетельство", только не то, что подтверждает, а процесс осуществления этого свидетельства - видения (знания того, чему явился свидетелем), от него глагол *свидетельствовать*. Устаревшее управление слова "свидетельство" тоже допускает род. и  дат. п. - чего? чему? ("Он был свидетельством тому").

У Ефремовой в словаре есть такое значение слова "свидетельствовать"-

2) Служить свидетельством

http://enc-dic.com/efremova/Svidetelstvovat-97408.html

Вот и получается: свидетельствовать происходящему = быть свидетельством происходящему. Видно, это стилизация под старину, под церковный язык. Не знаю, насколько это уместно в данном контексте, но если речь о папе, то, видимо, возможно.

Answer (score 2):

Словарь русского языка, том IV, 1961 (с пометкой-фразеология):

**свидетельствовать (*кому*) почтение (или уважение, благодарность и т.п.) -** выражать свое почтение (уважение, благодарность и т.п.) кому-либо (*устар.*).

Возможно, устаревший оборот *в наше время* используется с каким-то *особым* смыслом? Возможно, и ошибочно.
Вот примеры, похожие на Ваше предложение:

*Все, и ныне здравствующие, и почившие, и те, о ком всего парой слов упомянуто было, как будто я сам лично свидетельствовал происходящему в тени Кремлевских стен...*
[**Кремлевские призраки**](https://ficbook.net/readfic/5012360/12932041?show_comments=1)

*Важно постоянно свидетельствовать происходящему внутри вас, позволять быть всему.*
[**Школа единого учения**](https://vk.com/wall-35374352_83)

Окончательный вывод? Не решусь...

Comment: Ваши практические примеры далеки от словарного: в нём глагол используется как _переходный_ - старый фразеологизм "засвидетельствовать почтение" (что?) опирается на слово в винительном падеже, без которого не сочетается с дополнением в дательном падеже. В двух других случаях глагол выступает как _непереходный_ и заменяет синонимическое выражение "быть свидетелем" ("чему" - как и в примере из вопроса).

Comment: Да-да, конечно! - поэтому я и не делала никаких выводов. Только пыталась показать, что  оборот  " свидетельствовать происходящему" существует и привела примеры. А в словаре 1961 года такого оборота  нет. Оформите свой комментарий как ответ - пусть его увидят и оценят все.  Простите, не мне Вам давать советы...