# Управление: можно ли свидетельствовать чему-либо?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

> Папа Климент XIII (1758–1769) был рождён в Венеции, но на протяжении
>   всей своей римской жизни так или иначе свидетельствовал происходящему.
>   На его памяти состоялся первый пуск фонтана – в 1732 году, когда был
>   закончен фасад дворца Поли.

Может, это стилистически устаревшее управление, тогда его трогать не стоит...

Comment: Это здесь начинали разбирать: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431461/%d0%a1%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85

Comment: ...И не закончили. У Люси осторожное: *Вот и получается: свидетельствовать происходящему = быть свидетельством происходящему. Видно, это стилизация под старину, под церковный язык. **Не знаю, насколько это уместно в данном контексте**, но если речь о папе, то, видимо, возможно.*

Comment: В этом видении Бог стоял рядом с ним и говорил: "Дерзай, Павел; ибо как ты свидетельствовал о Мне в Иерусалиме, так НАДЛЕЖИТ ТЕБЕ СВИДЕТЕЛЬСТВОВАТЬ И В РИМЕ". (Деян. 23,11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Папа Климент XIII (1758–1769) был рождён в Венеции, но на протяжении всей своей римской жизни так или иначе **"свидетельствовал" происходящему.**

**Окказионализм:** свидетельствовал  происходящему – был свидетелем происходящего (можно заключить в кавычки).

https://infourok.ru/statya-neologizmi-v-sovremennom-russkom-yazike-1720873.html

Разновидностью авторских неологизмов являются окказионализмы. Это авторские неологизмы, созданные **по необычным моделям.** Они не существуют вне конкретного контекста.

Так, находим у А. С. Пушкина слова огончарован, кюхельбеккерно, у В. В. Маяковского: любеночек, что значит ребеночек и испешеходить, в значении исходить.